# Бот Telegram Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем добрый день!

Решила попробовать написать простого Telegram бота (просто свое любопытство) и наткнулась на ряд ошибок:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
 File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 356, in connect
ssl_context=context)
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
session=session
File 

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 356, in connect
ssl_context=context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
session=session
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "text.py", line 7, in <module>
bot.send_message(*id чата*, "Hi")
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 480, in send_message
reply_markup, parse_mode, disable_notification))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 140, in send_message
return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 495, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Я читала, что это связано с ssl, но самой решить не удалось, к сожалению. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скорее всего не ssl, а с блокировкой из-за РКН

Comment: Ох, точно. У самой Telegram через прокси работает. 
Установка VPN меня может спасти?

Comment: Не уверен. Возможно понадобится указывать вручную через какую прокси запросы будут ходить, например для использования Tor через sock5 для requests: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/93a07435bb6600e59ef6865fd4d08df124a25e13/using_tor/with_module_requests.py

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!
Вопрос решился. Заработало. Что-то я совсем забыла, что через прокси сижу)

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения перед всеми.

Для тех у кого вылезла подобная ошибка - скорее всего в телеге вы сидите через встроенный прокси, поэтому установите VPN, хотя бы на время тестирования бота.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Получается, если просто установить VPN, то все запросы прозрачно будут через него ходить? :)

Comment: Прозрачно )0)))0

Comment: Какая разница как вы сидите. Ошибка при запуске бота?